# Python batch process parameter substitution issue

Tags: windows, python-3.x, batch-file, subprocess

I have a one line command that I can run in CMD to populate a program with some parameters. The command its the following:

```
FOR /L %I in (16,1,20) DO "C:\Path\To\Program\program_executable.exe" --do-things="C:\Path\this.item|C:\Path\that%I.item|Text%I"
```

The thing is that I'm trying to achieve the same in Python 3.X and I'm unable to correctly pass the parameter information (--do-things="C:\Path\this.item|C:\Path\that%I.item|Text%I"). I've tried with `subprocess.Popen`, `system.call` and with both using a list of executable + parameter and a string of all the line all together:

```
['C:\\Path\\To\\Program\\program_executable.exe', '--do-things="C:\\Path\\this.item|C:\\Path\\that16.item|Text16"]
```

and

```
r'C:\\Path\\To\\Program\\program_executable.exe --do-things="C:\\Path\\this.item|C:\\Path\\that16.item|Text16'
```

The only thing I can do its start the program (as it calls the command), but it doesn't seem to be passing the args to it. I think the issue is that the args need the "" inside and Python doesn't seem to be able to properly send them, despite that I've tried escaping them just in case.

The CMD command that it should launch, should be something like this:

```
C:\>"C:\Path\To\Program\program_executable.exe" --do-things="C:\Path\this.item|C:\Path\that20.item|Text20"
```

Any idea how to achieve this from Python 3.X?

Comment: Since you won't be using the shell, double quotes are only used to help the child process create an `argv` array when a command-line argument has spaces. `subprocess.Popen` (the `call` function is a convenience wrapper that calls `Popen`) forms a command line by calling `list2cmdline`, which adds quoting when required. Try `for i in range(16, 21): subprocess.call([r'C:\Path\To\Program\program_executable.exe', r'--do-things=C:\Path\this.item|C:\Path\that%d.item|Text%d' % i])`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The program doesn't really like the args as that, since it only launches, but doesn't do anything with the parameter --do-things that we're adding to the executable.

Comment: Unfortunately `list2cmdline` isn't a sure bet because Windows programs are started with a command-line string. It assumes the program is following Microsoft's rules for parsing the command-line with respect to spaces, quoting, and escaping. If you have a program that follows its own rules, you need to build the command line manually. Try: `for i in range(16, 21): subprocess.call(r'C:\Path\To\Program\program_executable.exe --do-things="C:\Path\this.item|C:\Path\that%d.item|Text%d"' % i)`.